# How should I manage multiple images in C#

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

I am trying to write a program in C# that allows the user to select a folder, then show the images in it one at a time, changing the image by the mean of two buttons (i.e. a picture viewer). Then the user may use some controls to do some operations on the current image such as changing the colours, create a new image from the average colors of three images, etc.

Right now, it works well but I am only able to load one image at a time using the "OpenFileDialog", using this code (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Image-Edge-Detection-5c5a0dc2/view/Reviews).

```
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Title = "Select an image file.";
        ofd.Filter = "Png Images(*.png)|*.png|Jpeg Images(*.jpg)|*.jpg";
        ofd.Filter += "|Bitmap Images(*.bmp)|*.bmp";

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(ofd.FileName);
            originalBitmap = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(streamReader.BaseStream);
            streamReader.Close();

            previewBitmap = originalBitmap.CopyToSquareCanvas(picPreview.Width);
            picPreview.Image = previewBitmap;

            ApplyFilter(true);
        }
```

What I would especially like to avoid is pre-loading all of the images to arrays or something like that, since it would consume a lot of memory.

FYI, here is what look like the code used to modify the image.

```
        BitmapData sourceData = sourceBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0,
                                 sourceBitmap.Width, sourceBitmap.Height),
                                                   ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                                              PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        byte[] pixelBuffer = new byte[sourceData.Stride * sourceData.Height];
        byte[] resultBuffer = new byte[sourceData.Stride * sourceData.Height];

        Marshal.Copy(sourceData.Scan0, pixelBuffer, 0, pixelBuffer.Length);
        sourceBitmap.UnlockBits(sourceData);

        //
        // Here would be the image processing    
        //

        Bitmap resultBitmap = new Bitmap(sourceBitmap.Width, sourceBitmap.Height);

        BitmapData resultData = resultBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0,
                                 resultBitmap.Width, resultBitmap.Height),
                                                  ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
                                              PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        Marshal.Copy(resultBuffer, 0, resultData.Scan0, resultBuffer.Length);
        resultBitmap.UnlockBits(resultData);

        return resultBitmap;
```

I have read on Image lists (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761389%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but I was not able to "manipulate" the images.

So, in short how can I select a folder and display one the images in it one at a time?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use either the *Directory.GetFiles*, *Directory.EnumerateFiles*, *DirectoryInfo.GetFiles* or *DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles* method to get the names of the files in a directory, and the rest i think you can easily figure out...

Comment: the reults of the above methods are lists of filenames. `Imagelist` is the opposite, as it contains the images themselves - just what want to avoid..

Comment: Ok I'm trying to implement it right now, thanks!

Comment: Thanks elgonzo and TaW, I have been able to get it work. As a beginner on SO, should I answer my question with a code example, or since there were no upvotes to the question I consider it OK with these comments?